# Query is always execute before than AOP in SpringBoot and MyBatis application for dynamic datasource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, mybatis

Here , I want to make a SpringBoot and MyBatis application use dynamic datasource by AOP; But the AOP is always execute after query from database, so switch datasource is invalid because select is finished.

All my code is in https://github.com/helloworlde/SpringBoot-DynamicDataSource/tree/aspect_dao

My dependence is

```
compile('org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:1.3.1')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
```

And application.properties

```
application.server.db.master.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

application.server.db.master.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/redisapi?useSSL=false
application.server.db.master.port=3306
application.server.db.master.username=root
application.server.db.master.password=ihaveapen*^@#
#application.server.db.master.database=123456
#
## application common config
application.server.db.slave.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
application.server.db.slave.url=jdbc:mysql:/localhost/redisapi2?useSSL=false
application.server.db.slave.port=3306
application.server.db.slave.username=root
application.server.db.slave.password=123456
#application.server.db.slave.database=redisapi

mybatis.type-aliases-package=cn.com.hellowood.dynamicdatasource.mapper
mybatis.mapper-locations=mappers/**Mapper.xml
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE product(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  price DOUBLE(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

DataSourceConfigur.java

```
    package cn.com.hellowood.dynamicdatasource.configuration;

    import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
    import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
    import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    @Configuration
    public class DataSourceConfigurer {


        @Bean("master")
        @Primary
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.server.db.master")
        public DataSource master() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }


        @Bean("slave")
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.server.db.slave")
        public DataSource slave() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }


        @Bean("dynamicDataSource")
        public DataSource dynamicDataSource() {
            DynamicRoutingDataSource dynamicRoutingDataSource = new DynamicRoutingDataSource();
            Map<Object, Object> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>(2);
            dataSourceMap.put("master", master());
            dataSourceMap.put("slave", slave());

            // Set master datasource as default
            dynamicRoutingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(master());
            // Set master and slave datasource as target datasource
            dynamicRoutingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);

            // To put datasource keys into DataSourceContextHolder to judge if the datasource is exist
            DynamicDataSourceContextHolder.dataSourceKeys.addAll(dataSourceMap.keySet());
            return dynamicRoutingDataSource;
        }


        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mybatis")
        public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean() {
            SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
            // Here is very important, if don't config this, will can't switch datasource
            // put all datasource into SqlSessionFactoryBean, then will autoconfig SqlSessionFactory
            sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dynamicDataSource());
            return sqlSessionFactoryBean;
        }


        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dynamicDataSource());
        }
    }
```

DynamicRoutingDataSource.java

```
package cn.com.hellowood.dynamicdatasource.configuration;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource;

public class DynamicRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        logger.info("Current DataSource is [{}]", DynamicDataSourceContextHolder.getDataSourceKey());
        return DynamicDataSourceContextHolder.getDataSourceKey();
    }
}
```

- DynamicDataSourceContextHolder.java

  ```
  package cn.com.hellowood.dynamicdatasource.configuration;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  public class DynamicDataSourceContextHolder {


      private static final ThreadLocal<String> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<String>() {
          @Override
          protected String initialValue() {
              return "master";
          }
      };


      public static List<Object> dataSourceKeys = new ArrayList<>();


      public static void setDataSourceKey(String key) {
          contextHolder.set(key);
      }


      public static String getDataSourceKey() {
          return contextHolder.get();
      }


      public static void clearDataSourceKey() {
          contextHolder.remove();
      }


      public static boolean containDataSourceKey(String key) {
          return dataSourceKeys.contains(key);
      }
  }
  ```
- DynamicDataSourceAspect.java

  ```
    package cn.com.hellowood.dynamicdatasource.configuration;

  import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
  import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
  import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
  import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
  import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
  import org.slf4j.Logger;
  import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
  import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


  @Aspect
  @Order(-100) // To ensure execute before @Transactional
  @Component
  public class DynamicDataSourceAspect {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DynamicDataSourceAspect.class);

  private final String QUERY_PREFIX = "select";

  @Pointcut("execution( * cn.com.hellowood.dynamicdatasource.mapper.*.*(..))")
  public void daoAspect() {
  }


  @Before("daoAspect()")
  public void switchDataSource(JoinPoint point) {
      if (point.getSignature().getName().startsWith(QUERY_PREFIX)) {
          DynamicDataSourceContextHolder.setDataSourceKey("slave");
          logger.info("Switch DataSource to [{}] in Method [{}]",
                  DynamicDataSourceContextHolder.getDataSourceKey(), point.getSignature());
      }
  }


  @After("daoAspect())")
  public void restoreDataSource(JoinPoint point) {
      DynamicDataSourceContextHolder.clearDataSourceKey();
      logger.info("Restore DataSource to [{}] in Method [{}]",
              DynamicDataSourceContextHolder.getDataSourceKey(), point.getSignature());
  }
  ```

  }

And have Controller, Service and Dao for query, But although I set Order of aspect as -100, it still execute query before AOP, could anyone find where is wrong, Thank you very much.
[This is log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcmvx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fixed this issue, Because I injected Bean of DataSourceTransactionManager, So transaction will be open in Service, so the aspect of DAO is not work until transaction finished.

Delete this code:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dynamicDataSource());
}
```